# gnu C++ hash_map: erasing a key: defined?

Tags: c++, g++, hashmap

Consider the following program, which is a minimal example trying to reproduce a problem with some legacy code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ext/hash_map>

// Define a hash for std::string class so we can use it as keys
// in hash_map below.
namespace __gnu_cxx {
    template <>
        struct hash<std::string> {
            size_t operator() (const std::string& x) const {
                return hash<const char*>()(x.c_str());
            }
        };
}

// Data class contains a string
class Data {
    public:
        std::string s;
        Data() { s = "foobar"; }
        Data(std::string s_) : s(s_) {}
};

// Map keyed by string.  Values are Data instances
typedef __gnu_cxx::hash_map<std::string, Data> DataMap;

int main()
{
    DataMap m;
    std::string key = "test";

    // I am storing a "Data" instance d, for "key".  d.s is the same as key.
    Data d = Data(key);
    m[key] = d;

    DataMap::iterator it = m.find(key);
    if (it == m.end()) {
        std::cerr << "not there " << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    Data *dp = &it->second;
    // Question about the following line.  Is the behavior well-defined?
    m.erase(dp->s);

    return 0;
}
```

I am storing my class `Data` instances in a `hash_map`.  I search for a particular data member using a `key`, and then erase that value using `m.erase(dp->s)`.  `m.erase(dp->s)` will delete the object pointed to by `dp`.  Am I allowed to use `dp->s` in the call to `erase()`, or must I first make a copy and then `erase()`:

```
std::string key_to_delete = dp->s;
m.erase(key_to_delete);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.1/hashtable_8h-source.html), it seems as if even after the node (the pair pointed to by `it`) is deleted, the key passed to the `erase` function is still referenced. If `dp` is deleted, then the reference to `dp->s` becomes invalid. Yet the implementation of `hash_map` is still trying to dereference it. Fail.

You would need to pass something that is guaranteed to stay valid for the call to `erase`.

You could

```
m.erase(key);
```

Or you can use the iterator returned by `find` to do the erase:

```
m.erase(it);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is counter-intuitive, but now I have proof in the source code.

Comment: I can't use `key` or `it` directly because the actual code is a bit more complex and the point where things are erased from the hash map, I don't have access to `key` or `it` anymore.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to make a copy (or a follow-up question!)